Chassidish (accent) recordings of prayer
Where can one find recordings of prayers (e.g Sheme and Ashrei) said in chassidish style lashon hakodesh. YouTube isn’t great for it.

Which chassidic style are you interestedin, different chasidim pronounce words differently (Russian, polish, Garcia, Hungary)

@yoreinu, I am interested in the Satmar style. Such as where ברוך is pronounced like BUREEK.

The National Library of Israel has hundreds of such recordings. If you add a more specific search term in this site, you'll find what you want: https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?query=any,contains,%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%94&tab=default_tab&search_scope=Local&vid=NLI&mfacet=rtype,include,ethnographic-recording,1&lang=en_US&offset=0

Here is link to a recording of the rebbe of Klausenburg. His Havara (or as the OP states, his “style”) is the same as that of the rebbe of Satmar.
(Don't want to cause any confusion, but the Klausenburger Rebbe is from Galicia, so some vowels might be pronounced sharper then in Satmar, but for the purposes of this question it doesn't matter)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yqHsYCsbRw
This recording is great, as it allows you to follow along by highlighting the words the Rebbe is praying.


What do you mean “sharper”?

@QwertyCTRL. the segol might sound something like an "ey" for example "Keysser" and not "Kesser"

Is that the only thing? Or do you mean that many vowels in the Galician accent are diphthongs, while the same vowels in the Satmar accent are not?

@QwertyCTRL. You lost me at diphthings, sorry

Diphthongs are things like ey, ow, oy, instead of normal vowels like e, o, or a. Diphthongs are common in Ashkenazic accents. You wrote that the Galician accent is “sharper”, which you said means that Segol is a diphthong (ey). I am asking if that’s just one example of what “sharp” means, or if the special pronunciation specifically of Segol is the only thing that defines “sharpness” here.
